# Voltage regulator before or after LC filter?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise, low-pass, linear-regulator

When using both an LC filter and voltage regulator to clean up the output from a SMPS, what order should the two elements be in?

Comment: It depends on the LC filter and voltage regulator specifically used. Those in turn depend on the SMPS and what spectrum you are trying to clean up.

Comment: ^^^ is right but barring any way to really analyze it, and if I had only one shot at a board spin and had to take my best guess, I'd put it before the regulator.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also be inclined to put it before the regulator, since you'd lose some load regulation performance if it is after it. However I've seen many issues with LC's between a switcher and another regulator, as the LC will increase the input supply impedance looking from the downstream regulator. This could starve it of the current it needs during start-up or load transients and could cause the system to be unstable in some instances. As a general rule the resonant point of the LC should be 10x the bandwidth of the downstream regulator, so the two don't "fight each other".

The better option may be to get a regulator with better PSRR in the frequency range of interest, assuming that frequency is less than ~1 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that a Ferrite Bead in series, feeding a LARGE shunting capacitor and also the Voltage Regulator ---- is not the useful mindset.

Don't use a Ferrite Bead, unless in series with some LARGE lumped inductor.

And you may need to dampen the LC filter --- I'd do that with a 2nd capacitor have the approprioate R value  in series.

R_dampen = sqrt( L /  C ), thus 1uH and 100uF need

R_dampen = sqrt( 1u / 100uF) == sqrt(0.01) == 0.1 ohm

And the capacitor ESR may  suffice.